# Picking a Option from a cell by a value in ms excel

Tags: excel, formula

i'm looking for a formula where i can copy text from A to D option according to the option text in Ans column. see the attachment for more information.

if the **Ans** column has value **B** than value from **option B** should print in **AnsText** Column and so on.

[image: Select right answer from the given option according to Answer option]

Answer (score 0):

Try any of following formulas.

```
=INDEX(B4:E4,MATCH(F4,B3:E3,0))
=XLOOKUP(F4,B3:E3,B4:E4)
=FILTER(B4:E4,B3:E3=F4)
=HLOOKUP(F4,B3:E4,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: these formulas is not working when i have plenty of rows when i drag the formula to all the rows. the address of  B3:E3 changes when i drag the formula.

Comment: Then you have to use absolute reference like `=INDEX(B4:E4,MATCH(F4,$B$3:$E$3,0))`

Comment: =INDEX(B4:E4,MATCH(F4,$B$3:$E$3,0))  This formula works fine now. Thanks Harun24hr

Comment: Glad to know. If the formula works then please accept the answer (tick mark it).

Answer (score 0):

If A, B, C and D are always going to be in alphabetical order, then the lookup function will work best.

```
=LOOKUP(E2,A1:D1,A2:D2)
```

If not, the the HLOOKUP will need to be used

```
=HLOOKUP(E2,A1:D2,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: works only on first cell but when i drag the formulas down than it's not working.

Comment: In that case, an absolute reference for the first row will be needed.
`=LOOKUP(E2,A$1:D$1,A2:D2)`